# How GroupBox control size can be managed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have event Button that creates text box in run time.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click

  Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
  static Dim shiftDown As Integer
  static Dim counter As Integer

  counter += 1
  shiftDown = shiftDown + 30
  textbox1.Name = "Textbox" + counter.ToString()
  textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 10)
  textbox1.Location = New Point(10, 32 + shiftDown)
  textbox1.Visible = True
  GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)

End Sub
```

All the text boxes that has been created displayed in GroupBox control dynamically.

My question is how GroupBox control size can be managed according to quantity controls inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` property of groupbox.

Set the `AutoSize = true` if the GroupBox need to automatically resizes based on its contents; otherwise, false. The default is true.

[Refer the sample to dynamically control the size of GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autosizemode)